# Bootstrap 4: How to show the nav tabs as vertical view in mobile resolution?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, tabs

I have created the nav tabs using Bootstrap 4 and got the below output

[image]

However, I want to have the below output for the mobile view but my code is not working as expected.

[image]

Please help me to get the desired output as mentioned in the screenshot.

Thanks in advance.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.nav-tabs{
justify-content:center;}
}

.nav-tabs{
border:none;
padding:28px 0 0 0;
border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9}

.nav-link{
font-size:16px;
line-height:1.25;
color:#000;
border:none;
border-radius:0;
}
.nav-link.active{
border:none;
color:red;
border-bottom:4px solid red;
font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="exampletab">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs pt-2" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="one" data-toggle="tab" href="#one" role="tab" aria-controls="myactivites"
            aria-selected="true">one</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="two" data-toggle="tab" href="#two" role="tab" aria-controls="myactivites"
            aria-selected="true">two</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="three" data-toggle="tab" href="#three" role="tab" aria-controls="myactivites"
            aria-selected="true">three</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="four" data-toggle="tab" href="#four" role="tab" aria-controls="myactivites"
            aria-selected="true">four</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your style sheet (you can change max-width)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-sm-column{
          flex-direction: column!important;
    }
  }
```

Add this (nav-sm-column) class in ul tag

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs pt-2 nav-sm-column" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: then just add ( flex-nowrap ) class in ul tag 
no css needed for this